# Iterating over a list to append an array to a key/value pair

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a list like follows

```
ID    MODEL
001   Model A
001   Model B
001   Model C
002   Model A
002   Model B
002   Model D
```

I have to perform a query based on the ID, which I have working currently. It's currently performing one query per line in the list. It seems like it would be much faster to reduce the number of queries I have to run.

I thought if i had a hash that looked like this:

```
{
:001 => ["Model A", "Model B", "Model C"], 
:002 => ["Model A", "Model B", "Model D"]
}
```

I would be able to perform less queries.

The problem I am having is being able to determine how it is possible to iterate over a list like this and generate the hash necessary.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
id = parsed_line[0]
model = parsed_line[1]
hash["#{id}"] = models << model
```

inside of a loop that iterates over the text file. Where "models" is an array of the model list. 
The problem from here is that the hash then looks like this:

```
{
:001 => ["Model A", "Model B", "Model C", "Model A", "Model B", "Model D"], 
:002 => ["Model A", "Model B", "Model C", "Model A", "Model B", "Model D"]
}
```

I understand why it's happening, but I do not understand how to get the desired hash.

Comment: I don't which DB adapter and DB you are using... But I am sure you need to use **group by** *sql query* .to solve this problem..

Comment: Query might be -- `select id, (select model from table where id = table.id) from table group by id`..........

Comment: Your code doesn't tell us what `parsed_line` is, or what `models` is. Can you share your entire code instead of just these three lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `parsed_line` is an array that looks like this: `[ "001", "Model A" ]`. I don't know what `models` is, but I'm guessing it's unnecessary. Something like this ought to work:

```
parsed_lines = [ [ "001", "Model A" ],
                 [ "002", "Model B" ],
                 # ...
               ]

hash = {}

parsed_lines.each do |id, model|
  hash[id] ||= []
  hash[id] << model
end
```

Or, more simply (using [`Hash.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new)'s handy block default):

```
hash = Hash.new {|hash, id| hash[id] = [] } # If `hash[id]` isn't yet set when
                                            # we try to access it, automatically
                                            # initialize it with an empty array
parsed_lines.each do |id, model|
  hash[id] << model
end
```

Comment: you could just use `hash = Hash.new([])` instead of the block and it will perform the same function.

Comment: @engineersmnky That's not correct. `Hash.new([])` yields a Hash that will *return* `[]` for non-existent keys, but will not *set* the value of non-existent keys to `[]` (or anything else), which is what's needed here. Try it in your console: `h = Hash.new([]); h[:foo] << "bar"; puts h.inspect # => {}`

Comment: @engineersmnky It was a good thought, though, and a common "gotcha." I tried the same thing when writing my answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for pointing that out very strange behavior because if you run your code above it does exactly as you specify but then if you do `h[:foo] #=> ["bar"]`. Any idea where this value is kept because I now very intrigued?

Comment: Never mind I found it it stores the `object` as a default. which will be appended to on each consecutive call to a non-existent key. so `h[:bar] << "baz" #=> ["bar","baz"]`. Very interesting although I am not sure of a useful case for this as of yet...but it's early so it could just be lack of caffeine. +1 for the comments

Comment: Well, the use case is as a default. For example if you're doing math operations and want absent keys to return `0` instead of `nil`. It can save you the step of checking for `nil` (or doing `to_i`), but doesn't modify the original Hash.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you don't have any database. If all you have is a two dimentional array and you want to convert it into a hash, then this is what you should do

```
model_array= [["001", "Model A"], ["001", "Model B"], ["001", "Model C"], ["002", "Model A"], ["002", "Model B"], ["002", "Model D"]]

hash = {}
model_arrays.each do |arr|
  hash[arr[0]] ||= []
  hash[arr[0]] << arr[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one liner (sans declaration of `parsed_lines`)

```
parsed_lines = [
    ["001",  "Model A"],
    ["001",  "Model B"],
    ["001",  "Model C"],
    ["002",  "Model A"],
    ["002",  "Model B"],
    ["002",  "Model D"]
]
Hash[parsed_lines.group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| [k.to_sym,v.map(&:last)]}]
#=> {:"001"=>["Model A", "Model B", "Model C"], :"002"=>["Model A", "Model B", "Model D"]}
```

But it is probably better to do what @ArupRakshit stated and use a `group_by` query and skip this additional processing step.